# Gradle publish não envia arquivos ao repositório nexus (maven 2)

Tags: kotlin, gradle

Estou tentando fazer meu projeto enviar os arquivos JARs a um repositório nexus (maven 2) mas não estou conseguindo. O projeto é programado em kotlin.

Este fragmento de código é o mais próximo que eu consegui de um resultado:

```
plugins {
     id 'maven'
}

allprojects {
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url: "http://meusite.com/repository/meurepo-releases/") {
                    authentication(userName: variavelComUser, password: variavelComPass)
                }

                snapshotRepository(url: "http://meusite.com/repository/meurepo-snapshots/") {
                    authentication(userName: variavelComUser, password: variavelComPass)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quando executo a task `publish` isto ocorre:

```
20:02:07: Executing task 'uploadArchives'...

> Task :uploadArchives
> Task :environment:core:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :environment:core:compileKotlinCommon
> Task :environment:core:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :environment:core:classes
> Task :environment:core:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :environment:core:jar
> Task :environment:core:uploadArchives
> Task :environment:js:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :environment:js:compileKotlin2Js
> Task :environment:js:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :environment:js:classes
> Task :environment:js:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :environment:js:jar
> Task :environment:js:uploadArchives
> Task :environment:jvm:compileKotlin
> Task :environment:jvm:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :environment:jvm:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :environment:jvm:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :environment:jvm:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :environment:jvm:jar
> Task :environment:jvm:uploadArchives

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 14s
```

Mas quando acesso o nexus não vejo nada lá, continua vazio.

O que estou fazendo errado ou o que está faltando fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o bloco `uploadArchives` não estava sendo aplicado para todos os projetos como parecia.

Como o meu projeto raiz era só um container de outros subprojetos eu resolvi desta forma:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        if (it.plugins.hasPlugin('maven') ) {
            uploadArchives {
                repositories {
                    mavenDeployer {
                        repository(url: "http://meusite.com/repository/meurepo-releases/") {
                            authentication(userName: varComUser, password: varComSenha)
                        }

                        snapshotRepository(url: "http://meusite.com/repository/meurepo-snapshots/") {
                            authentication(userName: varComUser, password: varComSenha)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Observando vemos 3 mudanças importantes:

1. Troquei `allprojects` para `subprojects` já que meu projeto raiz não tem código-fonte.
2. Inseri o bloco `afterEvaluate` para executar o bloco após as primeiras configurações estarem prontas em todos os submódulos.
3. Adicionei uma verificação se tem o plugin maven antes de colocar o uploadArchives e coloquei apliquei o plugin em todos os módulos que quero exportar para o nexus, e com isso eu tirei o bloco `id maven` do bloco `plugins` do módulo raiz.

Desta forma eu consegui fazer com que cada módulo fosse enviado ao nexus individualmente.